# How to get page wise total of table fields in laravel TCPDF?

Tags: php, laravel, tcpdf

I'm using tcpdf to view data as pdf in my laravel project.
(I just attached sample pdf screenshots).

I have total of 14 records and when I print them in tcpdf I'm getting them as two pages as shown below.

**Page1:**

[image: Page1]

**Page2:**

[image: Page2]

In the 1st image final row is showing 11th record.

But I want it to show my total marks of current page. My expected PDF format is mentioned below.

**Expected Page1:**

[image]

**Expected Page2:**

[image]

How can I achieve this in tcpdf?
or is there any alternative for this to use in laravel?

Code I have tried:

```
 PDF::SetTitle('MultiSessionSummary');
   PDF::setHeaderCallback(function($pdf){
        $headertext = '<div style="text-align: center;">
        <h1 style="margin: 0;">Header</h1>
        </div>';
        $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP+15, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
        $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 10);
        $pdf->writeHTML($headertext, false, true, false, true);
        $pdf->Cell(35,0, '', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    });
    PDF::setFooterCallback(function($pdf){
        $footertext = "Version 0.1".date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $pdf->SetY(200);
        $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 10);
        $pdf->writeHTML($footertext, false, true, false, true);
        $pdf->Cell(35,0, 'Page '.$pdf->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$pdf->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    });
PDF::Cell(30, 6, 'Deposits', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
        PDF::AddPage('L', 'A4');
        PDF::writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x=5, $y=20, $html, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);
        PDF::Output('multi_session_summary.pdf');
```

My Blade:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="text-align: center;">
<h2>Games Report From {{$fromDate}} To {{$toDate}}<br>
Report Generated On {{date('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}</h2>
</div>
<div style="margin:0px;">
<table border="1">
  @if(COUNT($multiSessionSummary)!=0)
    <tr nobr="true">
      <th style="width:2%;text-align:center;">#</th>
      <th style="width:9%;text-align:center;">Bingo<br>Date</th> 
      <th style="width:8%;text-align:center;">Starting<br>Bank</th>
      <th style="width:8%;text-align:center;">Fill<br>Amount</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Drop<br>Amount</th> 
      <th style="width:10%;text-align:center;">Available Bal<br>(Liability)</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Deposits</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Total<br>Balance</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Player<br>Spend</th>
      <th style="width:9%;text-align:center;">Withdrawals</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Expected<br>Cash</th>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Total<br>Ante</th>
      <th style="width:10%;text-align:center;">Total Balance Remaining<br>(Liability)</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($multiSessionSummary as $summaryDetails)
      <tr nobr="true">
        <td style="width:2%;text-align:center;">{{$index++}}</td>
        <td style="width:9%;text-align:center;">{{$summaryDetails->BingoDate}}</td>
        <td style="width:8%;text-align:right;">${{$summaryDetails->StartingBank}}</td>
        <td style="width:8%;text-align:right;">${{$summaryDetails->FillAmount}}</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">${{$summaryDetails->DropAmount}}</td>
        <td style="width:10%;text-align:right;">${{$summaryDetails->AvailibleBalance}}</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">${{$summaryDetails->Deposits}}</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">${{$summaryDetails->TotalBalance}}</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">${{$summaryDetails->PlayerSpend}}</td>
        <td style="width:9%;text-align:right;">${{$summaryDetails->Withdrawals}}</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">${{$summaryDetails->ExpectedCash}}</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">${{$summaryDetails->Ante}}</td>
        <td style="width:10%;text-align:right;">${{$summaryDetails->TotalBalanceRemaining}}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  @endif
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what have you tried? we don't know your code

Comment: i have updated the code in my question @PhilippSander. As i mentioned above the pdf image i showed is sample one